# How do I uninstall Zentyal or can I revert to a 'clean' installation somehow?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, zentyal

I have installed zentyal 3.5 from the Zentyal PPA on a fresh ubuntu 14.04 installation.  After a few tests I want to uninstall zentyal.  Unfortunately, there are no instructions as to how to remove it.

What I did to remove the software was this:  I removed the zentyal PPA and ran `sudo apt-get remove zentyal-*`  But now, network manager doesn't work any more, and my system doesn't get DHCP assigned addresses.

How can I revert to a 'fresh' 14.04 installation to completely remove Zentyal?

Answer (score 2):

Never use the `remove` command with packageName ended with `*`, as it will possibly damage your system or erase other packages' requirements.

Run `sudo apt-get purge zentyal` to remove the installed `zentyal` package, 
and then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

It should fix the problem.